# Hot to center rectangle using phaser?

Tags: html, phaser-framework

This is my setup when I'm centering image sprite:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '', { init: init, preload: preload, create: create, update: update, resize: resize });

function init() {
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#5b0c26';
}

function create() {
    pic = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'imagerectangle');
    pic.anchor.set(0.5);
}
```

and it is working, image rectangle is centered but when I try to create rectangle using bitmap data it is not.

Here is code:

```
function create() {
    var graphics = game.add.graphics(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY);
    graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000FF, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    graphics.anchor.set(0.5);
    graphics.x = game.world.centerX;
    graphics.y = game.world.centerY;
}
```

Tried this example which I found on some forum, also not working:

```
var drawnObject;
var width = 100 // example;
var height = 100 // example;
var bmd = game.add.bitmapData(width, height);

bmd.ctx.beginPath();
bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
bmd.ctx.fill();
drawnObject = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, bmd);
drawnObject.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
```

Result:
[image]

How to create and center rectangle using bitmap data?

Thank you

Comment: Your approach seems correct. Did you try turning responsive design mode off just so that you're sure you're seeing the whole canvas?

Comment: @KamenMinkov - yes, and then is on same place or should I say in the center. What is wrong. Here is full code: https://jsfiddle.net/CroDac/moabhsex/ scale mode is commented

Comment: @KamenMinkov - I had to put drawnObject.x = game.world.centerX;
 drawnObject.y = game.world.centerY; in resize function :) Now is working. What should I do with stack, delete question o answer myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to put

```
drawnObject.x = game.world.centerX; 
drawnObject.y = game.world.centerY;
```

in resize function